# Angular2: data.json is not a function

Tags: angular

I'm developing an application with angular2 as frontendI want to log in from the client side to the server side but when I try to pass the credentials I have these errors in the browser console .

In run time it complains with:

> data.json is not a function

**This is my service code:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
isAuthenticated: boolean = true;

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    const headers = new Headers();

    const creds = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;

    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/StudentManager/login', creds, { headers: headers })

      .map( this.extractData )

      .subscribe(
          (data) => {
                     if(data.json().success) {
                window.localStorage.setItem('auth_key', data.json().token);
                console.log(username);
                this.isAuthenticated = true;
                    }
                resolve(this.isAuthenticated);
            });

    }
    );
  }

}
```

Here is a snapshot of the error:

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` instead of `data.json()`, because you already mapped your data to json using `extractData`

```
  .subscribe(
      (data) => {
            if(data.success) {
               window.localStorage.setItem('auth_key', data.token);
               console.log(username);
               this.isAuthenticated = true;
            }
            resolve(this.isAuthenticated);
        });
```

Comment: it worked , the error disappeared, but I don't know why it doesn't go inside the `if(data.success)`  even if I put correct credentials

Comment: check the value of `data.success`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is there is no function `json()` in your data object. Change to

```
.subscribe(
          (data) => {         
                window.localStorage.setItem('auth_key', data.json().token);
                console.log(username);
                this.isAuthenticated = true;                     
                resolve(this.isAuthenticated);
            });
```

Also you do not need to perform that check inside your data method, since if you are inside here the request was successful, otherwise it would have gone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/StudentManager/login', creds, { headers: headers })
      .map( res => res.json() )
      .subscribe(
          (data) => {
                     if(data.success) {
                          ....
                    } 
            });

    }
```